# Sphinx can't find the root module of my project

Tags: python, windows-10, python-sphinx

I have this sample project to learn how Sphinx works.

Directory structure is looking like this:

```
.
+--app
|  +--api
|     +--endpoints
|        +--address.py
|
|--docs
|  +--conf.py
|  +--index.rst
|  +--source
|     +--modules.rst
|     +--address.rst
```

I've added the relevant filepaths to my path in `conf.py`, as follows:

```python
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

project_root = Path(os.getcwd()).parent.absolute()
sys.path.insert(0, project_root)

path_app = os.path.join(project_root, "app")
sys.path.insert(0, path_app)

path_address = os.path.join(project_root, "app", "api", "endpoints")
sys.path.insert(0, path_address)
```

I have my ./docs/index.rst file, autogenerated by Sphinx:

```
.. Sky-Payment documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Fri Apr 16 17:23:31 2021.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Sky-Payment's documentation!
=======================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Then I have my `docs/source/modules.rst` file:

```
app
===

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   address
```

and my `docs/source/address.rst` file:

```
address module
==============

.. automodule:: app.api.endpoints.address
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

when I run `sphinx-build.exe -b html . .\_build` from `.\docs`, I get this error:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'api.endpoints.address' from
module 'app'; the following exception was raised: No module named
'app'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In your **conf.py**, put `sys.path.insert(0, "..")`

Comment: You didn't include the `__init__.py` files in the packages so there's no way to answer this. You also forgot to include `modules` in the toctree of `index.rst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **conf.py**, put `sys.path.insert(0, "..")`. The **../** relative path navigates to the parent directory. Since **conf.py** is located in **docs/**, the parent directory of **docs/** is the root of your project. This way, `sphinx` will be able to access your project files and it will be able to import your modules.